# Jenkins on Docker - Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:50000: unexpected error Permission denied

Tags: docker

I am trying to run Jenkins on Docker. Docker version - 18.09.2

I followed all the guidelines on hub.docker.com Still it is failing. The command I executed is:

```
docker run --name JenkinsServer -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v C:\Jenkins_Home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

The error message is:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint JenkinsServer (46bab1a1f5fcbe37d5a8394a4f97bd4b0b9b8c8be18c03b58696fda5daa774ef): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:50000: unexpected error Permission denied.
```

I checked whether the port is already in use or not through Resource monitor, but none of the services are running on 50000.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker on Windows 10 "driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414130/docker-on-windows-10-driver-failed-programming-external-connectivity-on-endpoin)

Comment: I tried that option. But still, it did not work. I restarted OS, Docker. But nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Run `Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 50000 | Format-List` in powershell to check which process using the port and kill the process using `taskkill /F /PID pid`.

Comment: I got this error.         Get-NetTCPConnection : No MSFT_NetTCPConnection objects found with property 'LocalPort' equal to '50000'.  Verify the
value of the property and retry.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 50000 | Format-List
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (50000:UInt16) [Get-NetTCPConnection], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_LocalPort,Get-NetTCPConnection