# Flask app running in host system but not in docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, devops

I am trying to run a Flask app (which seems to be working fine on the Windows host system) on docker.

This is my app.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import pickle
import numpy as np

with open("./rf.pkl", "rb") as file:
    model = pickle.load(file)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def predict():
    s_length = request.args.get("s_length")
    s_width = request.args.get("s_width")
    p_length = request.args.get("p_length")
    p_width = request.args.get("p_width")
    prediction = model.predict(np.array([[s_length, s_width, p_length, p_width]]))
    return str(prediction)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 5000)
```

As I said, this app is working fine on the host.

And here is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:latest

WORKDIR /home

COPY . /home

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD python flask_1.py
```

When I use `docker run -p 5000:5000 rf_api`, it says that the app is running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/. However, the browser can't reach the page.

I also tried `docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' <containerid>` which says that it is running on 172.17.0.2. But the browser can't reach this IP, either.

I can't figure out what is going wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

This is the output from 'docker ps'.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6rji.png

Comment: Try running `docker logs -f 1a22` and see if there is anything there when trying to open the page.

Comment: Hi, I tried that. Still getting 'That site can't be reached' from the browser.

Comment: Ok, but the logs don't show anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try to access `localhost:5000` or `127.0.0.1:5000` in your browser.

On Windows, run

```
docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.33.100:2376
```

Then try browse that ^^ `IP`:5000 in the browser.

Comment: Hi, I am running it on Windows. I did try both of those first before moving to 0.0.0.0:5000.

Comment: can you provide the output of `docker ps`(only the container that's running the flask app)?

Comment: Sure! I added the image to the original post.

Comment: Looks fine... Try to run `docker run -p 9999:80 -d nginx` and see if you can access other published ports. Try to access localhost:9999. You should see the nginx home page

Comment: If that works, it means there's a problem in the flask container, although it is unlikely...because you said you can see the `app is running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/` in the logs

Comment: Running ```docker run -p 9999:80 -d nginx``` gave me this error. ```C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint musing_lehmann (a29e5eeda82c92b953ed7ce46a8d30c```.

Comment: Very likely, something wrong with the docker engine. That nginx container has no reason to fail. Weird things happen in Windows from time to time. Try to restart docker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414130/docker-on-windows-10-driver-failed-programming-external-connectivity-on-endpoin

Comment: Looks like ```docker-machine ls``` is not available by default. I managed to install it on Git Bash. But the command returns a blank table. Also, have tried restarting docker many times. Maybe, I should just give up on trying to use docker from Windows.

Comment: It should work on windows as well, although I personally stopped running docker on windows long time ago, I know how it feels and I felt the same frustration spending more time to hack docker instead of focusing on the app :))

Comment: Will try doing it on an Ubuntu machine later. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

ssh into container Using:

`docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash`

Then curl the localhost:5000
if that doesn't work check project logs

Comment: Doing that gives me this error. """OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash\": stat C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash: no such fi
le or directory": unknown""